# Auto Numerations failed

Tags: support

Numeration starts from 1. again, when something is in between. I saw that in the correction, that [gigili made here](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3815/1224)

1. First point

something else, maybe some explaining on the first point

2. Second point (but the 2 is replaced with 1)
3. Third point (but the 3 is replaced with 2)

something else, maybe a hint belonging to the previous fact

4. Forth point (yeah, again 1)

How can I workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to indent your extra explanatory text, like so:

1. First point

   something else, maybe some explaining on the first point
2. Second point
3. Third point

   something else, maybe a hint belonging to the previous fact
4. Forth point

Comment: better than my trick!

Comment: @splattne the joys of markdown :)

Answer (score 2):

Just add two spaces at the end of the line preceding the extra information. Don't leave empty lines.

Example:

1. This is an
2. example {two extra spaces following ->}
   with an extra line
3. in an enumeration